# Show all post in wordpress with specific meta value

Tags: php, wordpress

I want show all post with "city" value when i select second option.

How to do?

i try next code but not work corectly.

```
<select>
 <option value="">All</option>
 <option value="<?php query_posts('meta_value=city'); ?>">City</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Explain your requirement in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,this may work

```
query_posts( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 
            'key' => 'meta_key_name',
            'value' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
) );
```